# Take input from a live source instead of from a file in live555

Tags: live-streaming, live555

I am just beginning to use live555 library. There are not much instance using live library. I get the image data from a camera and I have converted into h264 format. Now, the data is stored in the buffers in the program. So i need to stream live video and transmit it via RTP with RTSP Serve. But the most "test*Streamer" in the test programs read data from a file, how can I modify it so take input from the live source instead of a file? What data structures or objects should I use? It would be great help if someone could help me the some kind of guidance/tutorial or atleast some example to start of.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example of what you are after here:

https://www.imc-store.com.au/Articles.asp?ID=278

It is a c++ VS2010 project showing how to encode a raw RGB frame using FFMPEG, and then sending that discrete frame onto Live555 to be streamed.

The VS2010 project includes all the library and include files so it should simply be a case of unzipping, running the .sln file in VS2010, compile and run!

Also the VLC source code implements both FFMPEG and Live555, you could take a look at their code for some extra pointers!

Good luck!

Comment: Also from stack overflow's FAQ "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the test* files provided in the testProgs directory to read from stdin. to do so, you would need to "open" the device you want to read from before the main function is called for e.g

```
int stream = open("/dev/ttyUSB0",O_RDONLY);
```

Then in your `play()` function, before a bytestream source is created, you would need to call the `read()` function. That pretty much worked for me.